# How do you stop sh from interpretting the '\' character?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, posix

`I have a script where I am attempting to read from a manifest file, translate DOS paths in that manifest to UNIX paths, and then operate on those files.  Here is a snippet of code that I am trying to debug:

```
while read line
do
    srcdir=$(printf '%s' "$line" | awk -F \\ -v OFS=/ '{ gsub(/\r|^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "") } !NF { next } /^\\\\/ { sub(/^.*\\prj\\/, "\\prj\\") } { $1 = $1 } 1')
done < manifest.txt
```

My input file looks like this:

```
$ cat manifest.txt
\\server\mount\directory
```

When I debug my little shell snippet, I get the following:

```
+ read line
++ printf %s '\servermountdirectory
'
++ awk -F '\' -v OFS=/ '{ gsub(/\r|^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "") } !NF { next } /^\\\\/ { sub(/^.*\\prj\\/, "\\prj\\") } { $1 = $1 } 1'
+ srcdir=\servermountdirectory
```

So... Either at read or at printf, the `\` characters are being interpreted as escape characters -- how do I work around that?

Note... I know I could just run the `while` loop in **awk**... the thing is that in my real program, I have other things inside that `while` loop that need to be done with `"$srcdir"` -- and for this, **sh** is the right tool...  So I really need a solution in **sh**.

Comment: I think it's not quite a [duplicate] -- because in this case I didn't know if it was `printf` or read that was the problem and couldn't figure a way to tell the difference... but it's your call.  ;)  I really appreciate the answers here though.  Kamil was spot-on & Allan had some good things to add too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [posix read](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html):

> By default, unless the -r option is specified, < backslash> shall act as an escape character. An unescaped < backslash> shall preserve the literal value of the following character, with the exception of a < newline>. If a < newline> follows the < backslash>, the read utility shall interpret this as line continuation. The < backslash> and < newline> shall be removed before splitting the input into fields. All other unescaped < backslash> characters shall be removed after splitting the input into fields.

and:

> -r
>   Do not treat a  character in any special way. Consider each  to be part of the input line.

Just:

```
while read -r line; do
```

Also remember that without `IFS=` this will not preserve trailing and leading whitespaces.

Remember to always do `read -r`. Here is a good read: [bashfaq How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Also remember that reading file line by line is very inefficient in bash. It's way better to process the whole file using commands, tools, streams and pipes. If you have to read the file line by line, let the "preprocessing" stage parse the whole file, then read it line by line:

```
 awk .... manifest.txt |
 while read -r srcdir; do
    echo "$srcdir"
 done
```

or with command redirection, if you need the loop to run in the same shell:

```
 while read -r srcdir; do
    echo "$srcdir"
 done  < <(awk ... manifest.txt)
```

Comment: I completely agree with you but do we really need to read the file and print each line to `awk` before doing the processing? it is like doing twice the job... anyway +1

Comment: Thanks Kamil -- perfect!